# How rapid would air loss be in the event that a supermassive torus is punctured?

Tags: space-station, artificial-gravity

[image: Stanford Torus]

<sup>Artist's conception of a Stanford Torus. [[Source](http://new3.fjcdn.com/comments/Reminded+me+of+this+wallpaper+_aa5fd8ac5435376a76469a8fe81758a6.jpg)]</sup>

Consider a Stanford Torus of radius $ 4km $, with the inner radius of the torus ring being $1km$. Disregard structural stability issues. To simulate $1g$ of centripetal acceleration, it would rotate at around $0.5 rpm$ generating a rotational speed of ~$200m/s$ at the edge of the torus. This structure is then filled with air to maintain $1 atm$ of pressure, with a mixture of gases matching Earth's own atmosphere.

**What would happen if the hull is punctured? How rapidly would air escape from the structure? How would this variable change depending on the size and location of the puncture? How long would it take for the entire structure to fully decompress?**

Comment: Homework problem?

Comment: @OrganicMarble This is a problem far more complicated than what my school would give as homework ;) No, it's a project I'm working on. I personally don't know the mathematics that go into calculating air venting through a hole of any certain size, so I came here for help.

Comment: The numbers are arbitrary, I would be alright with an answer that explains the questions in an abstract form too. Then I'd use that understanding and apply it to my problem myself.

Comment: Try googling for compressible flow equations and/or choked flow.  The wikipedia article on choked flow has the equation you seek, then you can calculate the rest for yourself.

Comment: @OrganicMarble That's a great reference, but lacking a background in fluid dynamics, I can't even begin to solve that equation. That's why I asked here.

Comment: *"How rapid would air loss be in the event that a supermassive torus is punctured?"*  For a small puncture, in a structure of that size?  Minimal.  At least, that is what the engineering students who worked on the initial designs determined.

Comment: First off, the loss would be quite proportional to the puncture size. You can't expect the same results from a millimeter micrometeorite and from a space shuttle crashing into it and creating a 300-meter long breach as the rotation drags it through the coating.

Answer (score 1):

Plugging my values into the Wolfram Alpha [Venturi flow equation calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Venturi%20flowmeter&lk=3), I got my result:

```
320,000 litres per second
```

Formula:

$$Q = (\pi (D_1^2 \sqrt{\frac{2 (P_1-P_2)}{\rho}}\over(4 \sqrt{\frac{D_1^4}{D_2^4}-1))}$$

Q | flow rate
 
rho | fluid density
 P_1 | upstream pressure
 P_2 | downstream pressure 
D_1 | upstream pipe diameter 
D_2 | downstream pipe diameter 
(Q is the flow rate as measured by a Venturi flow meter)

I cannot verify this answer as correct.

Comment: Got a link? Can you show the formula?

Comment: What value did you use for the size of the puncture?

Comment: @called2voyage I used the larger diameter as 1000 metres, and the smaller diameter as 1 meter.

Comment: 1 meter does not sound like a small puncture, and 1000 meters is huge.

Comment: Are you using this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Venturi+flowmeter&lk=3 ?

Comment: Ok, I see by larger diameter you are referring to the upstream diameter which would be the diameter of the torus cross-section. Didn't you say the *radius* was 1km, so shouldn't $D_1$ be 2000 meters?

Comment: It does seem to be getting [about 320,000 liters per second](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Venturi+flowmeter&a=*FS-_**VenturiFlowmeter.Q-.*VenturiFlowmeter.rho-.*VenturiFlowmeter.da-.*VenturiFlowmeter.db-.*VenturiFlowmeter.pa-.*VenturiFlowmeter.pb--&f2=1.225+kg%2Fm^3&f=VenturiFlowmeter.rho_1.225+kg%2Fm^3&f3=101325+Pa&f=VenturiFlowmeter.pa_101325+Pa&f4=0+Pa&f=VenturiFlowmeter.pb_0+Pa&f5=2000+m&f=VenturiFlowmeter.da_2000+m&f6=1+m&f=VenturiFlowmeter.db_1+m&a=*FVarOpt.1-_**-.***VenturiFlowmeter.C---.*--), though I still have to say that a 1 meter hole is no small puncture.

Comment: Let's assume that like the ISS you can avoid debris larger than 10 cm. So if I plug a diameter of 10 cm for $D_2$, then I get about 3,200 liters per second.

Comment: That's significantly less. [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Venturi+flowmeter&a=*FS-_**VenturiFlowmeter.Q-.*VenturiFlowmeter.rho-.*VenturiFlowmeter.da-.*VenturiFlowmeter.db-.*VenturiFlowmeter.pa-.*VenturiFlowmeter.pb--&f2=1.225+kg%2Fm^3&f=VenturiFlowmeter.rho\u005f1.225+kg%2Fm^3&f3=101325+Pa&f=VenturiFlowmeter.pa\u005f101325+Pa&f4=0+Pa&f=VenturiFlowmeter.pb\u005f0+Pa&f5=2000+m&f=VenturiFlowmeter.da\u005f2000+m&f6=0.1+m&f=VenturiFlowmeter.db_0.1+m&a=*FVarOpt.1-_**-.***VenturiFlowmeter.C---.*--)

Comment: You seemed busy, so i edited in the formula from Wolfram Alpha, and linked to it. Hope that's okay. But would D_1 really be the diameter of the cross-section of the torus? Wherever an impactor strikes, the puncture will be perpendicular to that cross-section.

Comment: @kimholder That's the same number I got, so the math is right. My question is, am I correct in using the Venturi flow equation or should I use a different equation?

Comment: @called2voyage Even with a 1 metre hole, it will take around 30 hours for the torus to fully decompress.